Is there any way to improve the quality of a grow animation in PowerPoint?
I have a presentation that has a number of PNG images. They are of multiple pieces that fit together into a larger assembly. The presentation shows each piece individually and then I use some animation to bring them together into the full assembly.
One of the options as the slideshow is played is to press a button in a slide to zoom in closer on the smaller pieces of the assembly using the grow/shrink animation, in some cases up to the "Huge" (400%) setting. Unfortunately, doing so creates a very pixelated, distorted version of the original image.
Originally, in order to have the assembly look OK, I pre-scaled my PNG images down (28%) before I added them to my presentation and had everything scaled at 100% in PowerPoint itself. After I tried my zoom feature, I figured that was why the animation looked so terrible, so I instead added all the original images and used PowerPoint's scaling to shrink them to 28% using the settings shown below, which I hoped would fix the issue. Unfortunately, the grow/shrink apparently just uses the picture quality as it is on the slide after the scaling and not the original quality and scaling from that.

Is there any way to accomplish this zoom effect and have the quality of the image maintained?

As the transition completes, can you replace the scaled-down first image with the higher res image? Like, use the scaled down image to start the transition, but then fade in the higher res original as the transition animation completes?

@music2myear Technically, that would work, but then I might as well start high res, have it shrink as soon as the slide starts, then grow when they press zoom. The problem with either solution is the hi res versions are huge and will block parts of the slide. I want the small version present when editing the slide. Otherwise, the large image will be in my way while trying to edit. Which, is possible (I can use hide, edit, then unhide), but that becomes very cumbersome for 20+ slides.

@music2myear that does give me a couple similar ideas, though. I may try them in the morning. One is to have a separate slide with the large image, and do a custom slide show that transitions to that slide and automatically transitions back. Another is to have the large image off to the side of the slide and when the slide starts, have it disappear, then move into position invisibly on the slide, then fade in after zoom is pressed. Both are a pain in some way. I hate having images off slide, because PPT will sometimes scroll to a different slide when trying to work with them. Worth a try tho

Here's what worked:

Position the full res image to the right of the slide
Add Emphasis -> grow/shrink animation to the low res image, triggered on the press of my "Zoom In" button
Add "Disappear" animation to the high res image, after step 2, set to "Start with Previous" (This is so the next animation is not actually seen by the user)
Add Motion Path -> Line animation to the high res image, after step 3, with the end positioned at the middle of the low res image, set to "Start with Previous" ("disappear" happens instantly, so don't need to use "Start After Previous")
Add Entrance -> "Fade In" animation to the high res image, after step 4, set to "Start After Previous" so it occurs after the high res image is in place
Add Exit -> "Fade Out" animation to the low res image, after step 5, set to "Start With Previous" and for the same amount of time so it occurs simultaneously with the high res fade in

Side Effect: the simultaneous fade-in / fade-out creates sort of a "flash" which some people might not like but I actually do.
I started with Disappear / Appear and it works and is less "flashy". I'm sure if someone else sees this, they could experiment with other complementary exit / entrance effects.
